# Advance filter dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting below error while running this code
"Exact range has a missing".

If I put the fixed range, than it is running smoothly. Please assist.

```
Dim lastr As Long
lastr = Sheets("Associates Covered").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Sheets("Associates Covered").Range("A1:Q" & lastr).AdvancedFilter Action:= xlFilterCopy , CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:Q2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A10:Q10"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: What's the value of `lastr` when the error occurs?

Comment: Would the copyto ` CopyToRange:=Range("A10:Q10")` also need to be resized accordingly?